# How to set tag the ID to a checkbox android

Tags: android, checkbox, android-arrayadapter

I have created the custom adapter as follows.

```
public class sendivitesadapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item>{
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Item> items;
    private qrusers qrusers;
    private LayoutInflater vi;
    private String[] array;
    qrusers qrus;

    public sendivitesadapter(Context context,ArrayList<Item> items) {
        super(context, 0,items);

        this.context= context;
        this.qrusers =(qrusers) context;
        this.items = items;
        vi = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.getCount();
    }

    @Override
    public Item getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.getItem(position);
    }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = convertView;

            final Item i = items.get(position);

            if (i != null) {
                if(i.isSection()){
                    SectionItem si = (SectionItem)i;
                    v = vi.inflate(R.layout.checkboxlist, null);

                    v.setOnClickListener(null);
                    v.setOnLongClickListener(null);
                    v.setLongClickable(false);

                    final TextView sectionView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_item_section_text);
                    sectionView.setText(si.getTitle());

                }else{
                    sendItem ei = (sendItem)i;
                    v = vi.inflate(R.layout.checkboxlist, null);
                    final TextView title = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.contactname);
                    final TextView subtitle = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.companyname);
                    final CheckBox checkBox=(CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.checboxlist);
                    //checkBox.setTag(qrus.uid);



                //    Log.e("IDDDDDDD", text);
                    //checkBox.setTag("12");
                    checkBox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            String s=(String) v.getTag();
                            Log.e("IDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD", s);
                        }
                    });
                    if (title != null) 
                        title.setText(ei.contactname);
                    if(subtitle != null)
                        subtitle.setText(ei.companyname);

                }
            }
            return v;
        }   

}
```

And my activity where I have assigned this adapter to a listview is as follows.

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        JSONArray jarray;

        try {
            jarray= new JSONArray(result);

            name= new String[jarray.length()];
            company=new String[jarray.length()];
            uid=new String[jarray.length()];
            for (int i=0;i<jarray.length();i++){



                JSONObject jobj = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
                name[i]=    jobj.getString("Name");
                company[i]=jobj.getString("Company");
                uid[i]=jobj.getString("UserID");
                System.out.println(uid[i]);



                items.add(new sendItem(name[i], company[i], qrcheckBox));

                sendadapter  = new sendivitesadapter(qrusers.this,items);
                listView.setAdapter(sendadapter);
```

Now as you see I get the name ,company and uid from webservice. I get the ID of user in string array uid. Now I want to set the uid to the checkbox which i have created in custom adapter.  and on click of that it should hold the uid. How can i achieve this?

Comment: what problem getting after un-commenting `checkBox.setTag(qrus.uid);` line ?

Comment: it is showing me classcastexception...

Answer (score 1):

try below Custom Adapter

```
private class Demo_List_Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<Data_Model> {

        private ArrayList<Data_Model> inviteList;

        public Demo_List_Adapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                ArrayList<Data_Model> inviteList) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, inviteList);
            this.inviteList = new ArrayList<Data_Model>();
            this.inviteList.addAll(inviteList);
        }

        private class ViewHolder {
            TextView textView_FromPersonName;
            TextView textView_Subject;
            TextView textView_Body;
            TextView textView_Date;
            ImageView imageView_Star;
            CheckBox checkBox_MsgSelection;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            ViewHolder holder = null;
            Log.v("ConvertView", String.valueOf(position));

            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getActivity()
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_row_message_inbox, null);

                holder = new ViewHolder();

                holder.textView_FromPersonName = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.textView_FromPersonName);

                holder.textView_Subject = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.textView_Subject);
                holder.textView_Body = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.textView_Body);
                holder.textView_Date = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.textView_Date);
                holder.imageView_Star = (ImageView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.imageView_Star);

                holder.checkBox_MsgSelection = (CheckBox) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.checkBox_MsgSelection);
                convertView.setTag(holder);

                holder.checkBox_MsgSelection
                        .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
                                Data_Model inviteModel = (Data_Model) cb
                                        .getTag();

                                inviteModel.setChecked(cb.isChecked());
                            }
                        });
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            Data_Model inviteModel = inviteList.get(position);
            if (inviteModel.getJa_MS_IsRead().equals("0"))
                convertView.setBackgroundColor(getActivity().getResources()
                        .getColor(R.color.gray_background));
            else
                convertView.setBackgroundColor(getActivity().getResources()
                        .getColor(R.color.white));

            holder.textView_FromPersonName.setText(inviteModel
                    .getJa_ME_FromPesrsonName());

            holder.textView_Subject.setText(inviteModel.getJa_ME_Subject());

            holder.textView_Body
                    .setText(stripHtml(inviteModel.getJa_ME_Body()));
            String s[] = inviteModel.getJa_ME_CreatedDate().split("\\s+");
            holder.textView_Date.setText(s[0]);
            if (inviteModel.getJa_MS_IsFlagged().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                holder.imageView_Star.setImageResource(R.drawable.star);
            } else {
                holder.imageView_Star.setImageResource(R.drawable.star_unsele);
            }
            holder.checkBox_MsgSelection.setTag(inviteModel);

            return convertView;

        }

    }
```

holder.checkBox_MsgSelection.setTag(inviteModel); for to set tag

Comment: HOw can I set the string array uid[] id to the checkbox?